# DJANGO: FK field lookups through QuerySet exclude()

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

Im trying to exclude all objects from a django queryset that have a foreign key in another queryset. I am not having success using `exclude()` however. Please help.

Here is a snippet from the python shell:

```
>>> shipped = shipment_detail.objects.all()
>>> shipped
[<shipment_detail: 4>]
>>> fo = fill_order.objects.exclude(product_order__in=shipped)
>>> fo
[<fill_order: 2>]
>>> for x in shipped:
...  x.product_order.id
...
1
>>> fo
[<fill_order: 2>]
>>> for x in fo:
...  x.product_order.id
...
1
```

I am using django 1.7, python 2.7.7, postgresql 9.3, on debian wheezy.

**UPDATE**: Realizing i can see the sql django is using. Here it is. Obviously not what im trying to achieve. Looks like i need to explicitly tell django that i mean to reference FK id and not the record id.

```
SELECT "box_inv_fill_order"."id", "box_inv_fill_order"."product_order_id", 
"box_ inv_fill_order" ."date" 
FROM "box_inv_fill_order" 
WHERE NOT ("box_inv_fill_order"."product_order_id" 
IN (SELECT "box_inv_shipment_detail"."id" FROM "box_inv_shipment_detail"))
```

Comment: Does `fill_order.objects.exclude(product_order_id__in=[r.id for r in shipped])` make any difference? Thanks.

Comment: Thx @alecxe ! This in combination with looking at the actual sql made this a pretty simple and clear fix. Since i am referencing a FK in `shipped` queryset, I use `r.product_order for r in shipped`. Thx!

Comment: Don't forget that you can use `.values_list('id', flat=True)` to minimize resources and optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fo = fill_order.objects.exclude(product_order__in=shipped)`

Produces:

```
SELECT "box_inv_fill_order"."id", "box_inv_fill_order"."product_order_id", 
"box_ inv_fill_order" ."date" 
FROM "box_inv_fill_order" 
WHERE NOT ("box_inv_fill_order"."product_order_id" 
IN (SELECT "box_inv_shipment_detail"."id" FROM "box_inv_shipment_detail"))
```

This compares `product_order_id` against `shipment_detail_id`. **Not** what i intend!

**Solution**:

Utlizing @alecxe suggestion of `.filter(...__in=[r.product_order for r in shipped])`, creates a nested sql `SELECT` as the `IN` parameter.

```
SELECT "box_inv_fill_order"."id", "box_inv_fill_order"."product_order_id",   "box_inv_fill_order"."date" 
FROM "box_inv_fill_order" 
WHERE NOT ("box_inv_fill_order"."product_order_id" 
IN (4))
```